# Expandable and collapse tableview in swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8

I don't know how to implement expandable and collapse tableview in SWIFT. I searched, but nothing in swift. Kindly guide me. How to do that?

My required output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a framework like [CollapseClick](https://github.com/bennyguitar/CollapseClick).

**It's a framework written in Objective-C.**

[image]

But you can easily implement it in your Swift-Project. Just copy the `.h` and `.m` into your project and link it in your `Bridging-Header.h` file:

```
#import "CollapseClick.h"
#import "CollapseClickCell.h"
#import "CollapseClickArrow.h"
```

Comment: hi christian, I posted just for sample. But, I need from UITableView only. Very similar to that output. If we tap one cell, that cell gets expand, then if we tap other cell, that expanded cell get collapsed, similarly tapped cell get expand.

Comment: CollapseClick should do exactly that.